# Change font style of citation and bibliography entries

Tags: bibliographies, citing, apa-style, apacite

I am quite new to LaTex... I am trying to change the font style of the citation of an @misc entry. When cited, it always appears italicized (in text as well as bibliography entry). My goal is that @misc entries do NOT appear italiciced/bold/in quotation marks. I need them to be "normal". 
(I have to use the apacite style it is manfatory for my thesis.)
Please help, I am quite desperate ... :D

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, titlepage, a4paper, oneside]{scrreprt}


\usepackage{apacite}


\begin{document}
\urlstyle{same}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\setlength\bibitemsep{0.8\baselineskip}
\bibliography{references}
\urlstyle{same}

\end{document}
```

My Bibliography:

```
@misc{ARDBoerseTagessschau,
  title = {{ARD Boerse Tagesschau}},
  howpublished = {Retrieved May 15, 2019, from \url{https://www.tagesschau.de/wirtschaft/boerse/familienunternehmen-105.html}},
  year = {2019}
}
```

Many people recommend `\DeclareFieldFormat`. However, this did not work...
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typographic behavior you've noticed occurs because you didn't provide an `author` field for the entry, forcing the `apacite` package and associated bibliography style to display the `title` field in the citation call-out. And, as you've "discovered", the `title` field is set to be typeset in *italics*.

An inspection of the contents of https://www.tagesschau.de/wirtschaft/boerse/familienunternehmen-105.html suggests strongly that you should (a) change the name of the `title` field to `author` and (b) provide a new `title` field, viz., `title = {Familienunternehmen sind {Jobmotor}},`.

Observe that by writing `author = {{ARD B{\"o}rse Tagesschau}}`, i.e., by encasing the author's name in *two pairs* of curly braces, you inform BibTeX that it's dealing with a so-called "corporate" author and not with a person whose first given name is "ARD", whose middle name is "B{\"o}rse", and whose surname is "Tagesschau". This ensures that the entry will be sorted under `A` for "ARD" rather than under `T` for "Tagesschau", and also that the citation call-out will show "ARD Börse Tagesschau" and not just "Tagesschau".

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@misc{ARDBoerseTagessschau,
  author       = {{ARD B{\"o}rse Tagesschau}},
  title        = {Familienunternehmen sind {Jobmotor}},
  urldate      = {May 15, 2019},
  url          = {https://www.tagesschau.de/wirtschaft/boerse/familienunternehmen-105.html},
  year         = {2019}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt, titlepage, a4paper, oneside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
%\setlength\bibitemsep{0.8\baselineskip}
\usepackage{xurl}

\begin{document}
\cite{ARDBoerseTagessschau}
\urlstyle{same}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Mico, thank you so much for your quick help!! I tried your solution and it worked. However, using your solution creates a reference entry without dot (.) at the end. Is there a way to add the . ? Also, "Familienunternehmen sind Jobmotor" now is italic. This is much better than before. Unfortunately my professor does not want anything italicized when citing a webpage. Is it possible to suppress "Familienunternehmen sind Jobmotor" being italicized? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @LaTexNewbie - I'm glad my answer was useful. About the absence of a period ("dot") at the end of a formatted entry: That's a purposeful setting of the `apacite` bibliography style. If your professor can't stand this setting, then he/she shouldn't be forcing you use `apacite`. About not rendering the contents of the `title` field in italics if (and only if?) the entry at hand is a webpage: I don't think there's a general setting for that in `apacite`. You'll have to hand-edit the `title` fields so that they show, say, `title = {\textup{Familienunternehmen sind Jobmotor}},`.

Comment: @LaTexNewbie - More about the absence of a period at the end of the formatted entry if the final field is `url`: That's purposeful in the sense that showing a period in such cases, i.e., immediately after a URL string, might cause some confusion over whether or not the period is part of the URL string.  Again, this setting is very specific to the `apacite` bib style. If your professor can't abide this setting, he/she shouldn't be forcing you to emply this bib style.

Comment: Thanks again, Mico. Using \textup{} in the title field does the trick! :) I really dont know why my professor forces us to use apacite on the one hand and also wants us to change specific settings about this style... I am guessing that this is some guideline of his professorship and that he himself is not using LaTex.