# Change bibliography style of the title

Tags: bibliographies, bibliographystyle

I wanted to change the style of my bibliography. This is what I'm working with:

```
\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}   
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

And this is how my bibliography is looking:
[image]

I would like the title to appear in italics and the journal not. How can I change it? I am using unsrt style because it sorts the articles by appearance in the text and it's the most similar style to what I want.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide atleast one entry from your `bibliography.bib` file...

Comment: With bibtex (as you are doing there) that is not something you just change. That involves making a copy (under another name) of `unsrt.bst` and changing that copy. Is this a personal document, or something where the code needs to be sent elsewhere? Because then `biblatex` might be a better solution, and there styles **can** be updated from the preamble which is more or less impossible with plain `bibtex` styles.

Answer (score 0):

Before you provide more information about your bibliography, check if Mico's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/492128/260996) helps: